# $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} x^2 \int_0^x e^{t^3-x^3} dt$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

Plz solve this integral $$\lim_{x\to \infty} x^2 \int_0^x e^{t^2-x^2} dt = \frac{1}{2}$$

I tried solving this for like 3 days but couldn't even find the required answer even on online platforms like Wolfram.
Those of you who might doubt the authenticity of the question, I am attaching the source -

http://kvpy.iisc.ernet.in/main/2016-questionpapers.htm 
; Choose stream SB/SX ;
Question no. 12, page no. 5

Will attach image after gaining required points.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: This would be true if it was $\lim_{x\to \infty} x \int_0^x e^{t^2-x^2} dt$ instead of  $\lim_{x\to \infty} x^2 \int_0^x e^{t^2-x^2} dt$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici thanks for the edit. It would be really helpful if u can add a stepwise solution. Thank u

Comment: @hellgod07 you are asking Claude for a stepwise solution to another problem than the one stated, am I correct? If this is the case, then you should at least edit your question.

Comment: @Surb for the same problem

Comment: Thank @Surb for the edit, not me. Cheers.

Comment: @hellgod07 please make sure your question is really the one you want to address and if not, edit in consequence.

Comment: @Surb I hope it's ok now? If not plz feel free to correct again. I am new to stack exchange so I m nt really familiar with it. Thank you

Comment: @hellgod07 I think the previous formatting of the question was better... at least it gave the impression that you have put some efforts. 
Have you read Claude's comment? *Your integral seems simply wrong! (at least I doubt the answer is $1/2$ but rather $\infty$)* Are you sure the exponent on $x$ before the integral is $2$? If not simply take it away. I understand you are new to MSE, nevertheless please make sure the question you ask is really the one you want to answer.

Comment: @Surb r u satisfied now?

Comment: @hellgod07 It is not me who you need to satisfy but the community (note that I didn't vote to close your question....). In the link you give, the question is about evaluating $\lim_{x\to \infty} x^2 \int_{0}^x e^{t^{\color{red}3}-x^{\color{red}3}}dt$ which is different from what you ask here and what Claude proposed. Furthermore the solution $1/2$ does not appear... Anyway, the question you have asked here is answered by Badam Baplan and hopefully you are satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed the limit you ask about is infinity.  We can show this with L'Hospital's rule.

Let $$F(x) = x^2e^{-x^2}\int_0^x e^{t^2} dt$$

You are interested in $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} F(x)$.  Set $$f(x) = \int_0^x e^{t^2} dt$$
$$g(x) = x^{-2} e^{x^2}$$

Then $F(x) = \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, and we see that $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} g(x) = +\infty$$

This is just the sort of indeterminate limit form that L'hospitals rule deals with.
We calculate that
$$g'(x) = 2(x^{-1} - x^{-3})e^{x^2}$$
and $$f'(x) = e^{x^2}$$ (See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) if you need a reference for differentiation under the limit sign.)

Hence $$\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{x^3}{x^{2} - 1}$$

and by L'Hospital's rule we have $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} F(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2} \frac{x^3}{x^{2} - 1} = \infty$

That said, if $g(x)$ were instead $x^{-1} e^{x^2}$, you can see how things would work out nicely and the limit would be $\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

Let f(x)=$\int_0^x \exp(x^2) dx$ and $g(x)=x^{-1} \exp(x^2)$. Apply L'Hospital's Rule to $\frac f g$.

Comment: wile this seem to answer the suggestion of Claude Leibovici, it is (at the moment) not exactly the question asked by OP (but maybe they will edit it...).

Comment: Sir can u plz provide step wise solution. I m not able to apprehend it properly.